# How to change get method parameter into segments in mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the url like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/computer/products.php?cid=3
```

i have to modify by following segments.

```
http://localhost:8080/computer/products/3
```

is there any possible way to convert into segments in mod rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^computer/(\w+)/(\w+)$ computer/$1.php?cid=$2 [L,PT]
```

You can transfer any part from the original URL with [regex backreferences](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/intro.html#InternalBackRefs).

In your case:

```
^computer/ (\w+) /         (\w+) $
           ⇓               ⇓
computer/  $1    .php?cid= $2
```

In a concrete situation:

```
computer/ products /         3
          ⇓                  ⇓
computer/ products .php?cid= 3
```

If this does not work, check that .htaccess files are enabled:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Alternatively, you can place the rewrite code in an apache configuration file.

Comment: Not working @david i am receiving same error message.

Comment: Does your file exist (`[yourwebroot]/computer/products.php`)? Does it have read permission?

Comment: yes i have. if i call like this http://localhost:8080/computer/products.php?cid=3. its working. if i call like this  http://localhost:8080/computer/products/3. its showing object not found.

Comment: is there any alternate solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ /$1/$2.php?cid=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I am receiving Object not found!

Comment: Where is this htaccess located? It needs to be in root of your web site and make sure there are no other rules.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this easy code in your .htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/computer/products/([0-9]+)$ /computer/products.php?cid=$1

Hope I help you.
Marco

Comment: when i call this url in browser http://localhost:8080/computer/products/3. i am receiving object not found.